# Bundling reads or caching collections with Pymongo

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently running into an issue in integrating ElasticSearch and MongoDB. Essentially I need to convert a number of Mongo Documents into searchable documents matching my ElasticSearch query. That part is luckily trivial and taken care of. My problem though is that I need this to be fast. Faster than network time, I would really like to be able to index around 100 docs/second, which simply isn't possible with network calls to Mongo.

I was able to speed this up a lot by using ElasticSearch's bulk indexing, but that's only half of the problem. Is there any way to either bundle reads or cache a collection (a manageable part of a collection, as this collection is larger than I would like to keep in memory) to help speed this up? I was unable to really find any documentation about this, so if you can point me towards relevant documentation I consider that a perfectly acceptable answer.

I would prefer a solution that uses Pymongo, but I would be more than happy to use something that directly talks to MongoDB over requests or something similar. Any thoughts on how to alleviate this?

Answer (score 0):

pymongo is thread safe, so you can run multiple queries in parallel. (I assume that you can somehow partition your document space.)

Feed the results to a local Queue if processing the result needs to happen in a single thread.